# Is there a better way to make a facet menu?

Tags: php, faceted-search

### Overview

I have created a facet menu for my companies eCommerce solution. You can see a demo of this [here](http://mercury.demomycms.co.uk/products.php). The whole thing is several hundred lines of code spread over 4 files, so I won't include the whole thing here, but will paste any relevant code.

The basic flow of code is:

1. Load all products for the selected category
2. Load all constraints and facets (each facet also loads which products are linked to it at the same time).
3. Check for any active facets that have been selected by the user, and if there are any filter the original list of products down by these facets.
4. Run a query for each constraint to count the number of active products per facet, excluding any active facets in *this* constraint. This is because facets within a constraint should not affect each other.

I run a single query against the database to get a full list of valid products for the active facets, and then use a simple in_array check for the original list of products. This is the actual code in use at the moment:

```php
if(!empty($this->filters)) {

    //Get a list of product IDs that match the active facets
    $query = "SELECT p.pId 
        FROM products p 
        LEFT JOIN filterproducts fp 
        ON p.pId = fp.fpProductId 
        WHERE p.pDisplay <> 0 
        AND ( ";
    $or = "";
    foreach($this->filters as $constraint => $facets) {
        $query .= $or . "(";
        $subOr = "";
        foreach($facets as $facet => $set) {
            if($set) {
                $query .= $subOr . "fp.fpFacetId = " . (int)$facet;
                $subOr = " OR ";
            }
        }
        $query .= ")";
        $or = " OR ";
    }
    $query .= ") 
        GROUP BY p.pId 
        HAVING COUNT(p.pId) = " . count($this->filters);
    $results = $this->dbConn->query($query);
    if($this->dbConn->errno) {
        trigger_error('An error occured whilst loading products matching active facets.' . PHP_EOL . 'Query: ' . $query . PHP_EOL . 'Error[' . $this->dbConn->errno . ']: ' . $this->dbConn->error, E_USER_WARNING);
    } elseif($results->num_rows) {
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            $this->validProds[] = $row['pId'];
        }
        $results->free();
    }

    //Compare products with the list of valid IDs and unset any invalid products.
    foreach($this->products as $product) {
        if(!in_array($product->id, $this->validProds)) {
            unset($this->products[$product->id]);
        }
    }

}
```

### The Issue

I then run the same query again for each constraint, but leave out that constraint's active facets from the query. Instead of filtering the products, I count the number of matches and use this to display a number next to the facet name on the menu. However this means if I have 10 constraints, I have to run 11 queries (the original, plus one for each constraint). Whilst it works, it's not exactly efficient.

### The Question

Is this the only way for a facet menu to work? I cannot think of any other way, but surely there is a more efficient way to achieve this. I would be very grateful to anyone who can suggest a better way to create a facet menu.